# How to make a backup copy of a table at a specific date/time using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, backup

On 31 Dec 2011, I have to copy the data of one of my database tables into another table automatically at 11:59.

What steps should I follow?

Comment: Ask earlier? Are you just re-creating the table on the same server or are you looking to backup the table, i.e. create it on another server or take a copy?

Comment: both,. one table on same server. one on another

Comment: What's wrong with `create table as select ...` see, as per [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html).

Answer (score 2):

The best bet will be to use MySql Schedular, I know MySQL 5.1.6 come with this, check out [this](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/MySQL-Scheduler.html). For more on how you can backup MySql database [check out](http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.)

Using MySQL Schedular you can do something like

```
  CREATE EVENT MyEvent
  ON SCHEDULE AT TIMESTAMP '2011-12-30 23:59:00'
  DO
  SELECT * INTO MY_NEW_TABLE FROM MY_CURRENT_TABLE;
```

Comment: Thanks .Will try and back to u

Comment: Remember to turn on event schedular using `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`, incase the schedular has not been turned on.